# What reason has been given for the "standard array" being lower than the expected average from the rolled method?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, ability-scores, designer-reasons

When one levels up and gets an increase in maximum hit points, one can either roll or take the average roll *rounded up*. Statistically, you're better off with the non-random method.

For ability scores, the standard array is **15, 14, 13, 12, 10, 8**. Using the point-buy system yields scores in this same basic range. But, according to [AnyDice](http://anydice.com/articles/4d6-drop-lowest/), the average rolls for 4d6-drop-one are **16, 14, 13, 12, 10, 9** — slightly better and, crucially, providing the *likely* possibility of an 18 to start (with a racial bonus of +2) and a 40% chance of starting with at least one ability score at 19 or 20.

It seems odd to me that the designers didn't go the same route as with hit points: make the predictable choice be rounded up from the average. [This answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/48419/904) delves into the math and makes the same basic point — and ends up wishing that the designers had picked a slightly higher standard array.

We can all speculate on the pros and cons of this; I'm curious instead about *designer intent* and *official* references and commentary.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Designer Reasons

Comment: For reference: [Designer intent questions are considered off-topic on RPG.SE.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7968/33569)

Comment: Eh. This question was asked _and answered with an actual designer reference_ before that policy existed. And from the most-upvoted answer to that meta question, _Refrain from any campaign to root out and close old questions._

Comment: @mattdm Refraining from a campaign to root out and close old questions is true, but doesn’t amount to a blanket grandfathering order. When someone stumbles across one in the normal course of using the site it’s fair game to close. (I’ve historical-locked this since it is currently off topic and reopening off-topic questions isn’t useful.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Mike Mearls tweeted the following on 13 Jul 2014](https://twitter.com/mikemearls/status/488426873542946816):

> IIRC, **point buy models the most common outcomes of 4d6, drop lowest.**

(Emphasis mine. IIRC stands for "If I remember correctly".  I didn't know that myself. :))

His tweet seems to imply

1. That they relied on some other probability calculation tool instead of AnyDice
2. **The designer intent was, indeed, to use the most common outcomes of 4d6, drop lowest.**

(The short thread Mearls' answer appears in discusses ways and whys of adding / not having a 16 in the standard array.)

Comment: Hooray! A non-speculation answer for this! Thank you, and great find. :)