# What is the lowest modifier you can have on a skill check (while staying within official rules)?

Tags: dnd-5e, skills, optimization

I was watching some Critical Role last night, and one of the players had a -3 modifier to Insight (his Wisdom score of 7 didn't help). And that made me wonder:

What would be the lowest modifier you could create while staying within the normal, official rules?

Comment: Similar question, but about CON saves: [What is the lowest possible Constitution saving throw modifier for a player character?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/192663/what-is-the-lowest-possible-constitution-saving-throw-modifier-for-a-player-char)

Comment: Related, in being almost the exact opposite of this: [What is the highest total result one can get for a skill check?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/144371/52137)

Comment: Lowest *for any rolls* or do you want to count the lowest with temporary conditions like debuffs?

Comment: You used the word normal, but most of these questions rely on all sorts of setup that is far from normal. You might need to define this better.

Comment: @SeriousBri I think “normal” here pretty clearly means “not using any variants, official or otherwise.”

Comment: Does it have to be applicable for every skill / tool (let's say e.g. Sleight of hand check) or just for whatever skill happens to be able to be pushed the lowest?

Comment: Sorry to add more comments. but do other restrictions apply, like e.g. a level cap or a "no help from "friends" rule?"

Comment: @TobiasF. the question mentions no such restrictions and the "a" is a singular skill check, so as the question asked for that it will be the skill that one is able to push lowest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## -28 to all ability checks

I will give this a try and assume for the time being I can bring a nearly unlimited number of friends(or foes). I find it surprisingly hard to really push the modifier down, but this is my shot at it.

Lets start with the easy part, roll unlucky and you get a score of 3 in Dexterity, giving you a -4 for any ability checks you make.

### Spells: -10

Now some enemies will cast a number of spells at our target (we assume all possible saves fail):

- [Raise Dead](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/raise-dead) giving you -4 on ability checks
- [Synaptic Static](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/synaptic-static) You have to substract 1d6 from every ability check you make during the duration

### Magic items: -2

Now we grab ourselves some magic items to even further curse ourselves (quite literally):

- [Stone of Ill Luck](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/stone-of-ill-luck) (cursed): -2 to ability checks

### Enemies and "friends" abilities: -12

Have a College ot Lore Bard use their cutting words feature on you, giving you a penalty of one roll of their bardic inspiration dice. We assume the bard is at least level 15, so their die is a d12.

### End result

With that, we reach a total of **-28** to all ability checks.

Comment: Some more options/penalties can be found in [this answer to "What is the lowest possible Constitution saving throw modifier for a player character?"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/192668).

Comment: Most of these questions assume the worst possible rolls, not the best

Comment: @SeriousBri well if you want a low score to see how far it can go, I assume you want to maximize any rolls that further lower the score to reach the furthest maximum in the desired direction,hence why I used max rolls on anything that lower the result

Comment: I would assume that too, which is why I voted to close the really unclear question