# What is the highest possible bonus to a saving throw?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, saving-throw

What is the highest possible bonus to a saving throw?

Assume normal attunement limits, both for the character making the save and anybody helping them. I'm interested both in attribute-based saves and those not.

My question is generally for mainline, officially published content. Side content such as Ravnica backgrounds, Eberron races, Theros piety, planeshift content, epic boons etc., are also allowed but ought to be listed. You have as much time as you want to prepare, and the saving throw does not need to be repeated ever again. *Wish* only has listed results, but the immunity obviously does not count as it goes against the spirit of the question. Artificers can obviously go above the normal attunement limit.

Comment: Related: [What is the lowest possible Constitution saving throw modifier for a player character?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/192663)

Comment: Does it matter which saving throw? Are you looking for the highest bonus that can be applied to *all* saving throws? Does it count if it only applies to one type of saving throw?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov attribute based saves are obviously higher, but there might be some obscure bonuses that name one in particular that I do not know. I'm interseted in answers to both.

Comment: Do we know what type of saving throw we are about to make? Can we use Epic Boons? Unearthed Arcana? Planeshift materials? Optional Rules? Do we have any amount of preparation time? Can we use Artificers to have more than 3 attuned items? Do we have any amount of time during which we can prepare (setup rounds and those kind of things)? Can we use *wish*? Should the method we use be repeatable throughout a day or does a method that only works once (maybe even once *ever*) work?

Comment: Need more limits of what can and cannot be used. There are items that permanently increase attribute, so it's technically possible to get your some stat to 100 (and have +90 on all related checks) if you'd manage to find 40 Manuals of Bodily Health, for example (or live for 4000 years, since those manuals can be used once a century). Probably, you should set some starting conditions, like saying that all attributes are 20 and can't be increased permanently.
Also, should this check be done alone? Or should we suppose that we have a bunch of friendly casters, capable of buffing us?

Comment: @Sarge Attributes are hard capped at 30, so it's not a problem, actually.

Answer (score 8):

### +52+1d12+5d4

(Mainline content only, possibly incomplete)

Manuals (of Bodily Health, et cetera) let us raise ability scores up to a cap of 30, so we'll be assuming a +10 any time we reference an ability score.

Saver is a Artificer 17/Bladesinger Wizard 2/Divine Soul Sorcerer 1 - taking Artificer or Sorcerer at level 1 gives proficiency in Con saves. Assistants are a 15th-level Bard, a 1st-level Peace Cleric and a 6th-level Paladin.

Magic items - Artificer levels give us five attunement slots, we'll take a Robe of Stars, a Luck Blade, a Ring of Protection, a Stone of Good Luck and a Staff of Power. The first four all give a +1 bonus to saving throws, while the latter gives a +2.

The save is a concentration saving throw. Saver has:

- +10 Con
- +6 from proficiency
- +10 from Bladesong (add Int bonus)
- +10 from Flash of Genius (Int bonus again)
- +6 from magic items
- +10 from Aura of Protection (Paladin's Cha bonus)
- +1d12 Bardic Inspiration
- +1d4 from Cleric's Emboldening Bond
- +1d4 from Bless (cast by Paladin)
- +1d4 from Resistance (cast by Cleric)
- If you fail, Favored by the Gods allows you to add 2d4. Failing with this bonus is hard, but if we take enough damage we can manage it!

This gives us a total of **+52+1d12+5d4 - min 58, average 71, max 84.**

Comment: Artificer was published in Tasha's Cauldron of Everything, which would assume is under 'mainline'. I can add sourcing if required, but everything I used comes from the PHB, DMG, Xanathar's or Tasha's.

Comment: nope, no worries! Totally forgot they moved it...although Tasha's in entirety is optional. It isn't technically 'always-on core'

Comment: "Bounded accuracy" my foot.

Comment: @Michael Pretty sure bounded accuracy goes out the window if your DM gives the whole party manuals to get every stat to 30.

Comment: @NautArch The only “always-on core” in 5e is the _Player’s Handbook_, _Dungeon Master’s Guide_, and _Monster Manual_. And honestly even those last two are kinda optional, too; for a long time, the _PHB_ was the only book _to have_, and the game is still playable that way (lot more work for the DM, having to make up every monster, though).

Comment: @KRyan Kinda/sorta. Some books specifically call out their entirety as optional. Others do not.

Comment: @BlueHairedMeerkat , I may have missed it in your response, did you include the Supernatural Gift of a Blessing (of Protection) which gives a +1 to AC and saving throws (DMG pg 228)? If 84 is good, 85 is even better.